# Fixing quote escaping with bash script and sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash file processing some CSVs.  Some of the input CSVs are not formatted properly, so I want to fix them with sed.  The quotes are escaped like `\"` and not like `""`, so I call sed to change this.  In the command line this works perfectly:

```
sed -i 's/\\"/""/gi' input.csv
```

But inside a bash script this seems to do nothing.  I guess it has something to do with quotes and escape sequences, but what is the solution?

Comment: Note that your command line is a bit problematic.  While it may work with GNU sed, it will throw errors in other environments, because `-i` takes an option that is the extension to use for the backup file.  To get around this, be explicit regarding what part of the command line is the script.  `sed -i -e 's/\\"/""/gi' input.csv`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to escape the escape character `\` for that to work:

```
$ echo 'bla;\"bli bli\";otherbla' | sed -e 's/\\\"/""/g'
bla;""bli bli"";otherbla
```

for bash scripts, you need to make sure that the line you read from the CSV file is properly quoted when passing it to sed. Can you provide an example of the CSV file as well as how you read from the file?

Using `cat file | while read`, here is an example of the problem:

```
$ cat test.csv
bla;\"bli bli\";otherbla
ble;""bli bli"";otherbla
bli;\"blo\";otherbla

$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

cat test.csv | while read line;
do echo "$line" | sed -e 's/\\\"/""/g'
done

$ ./test.sh
bla;"bli bli";otherbla
ble;""bli bli"";otherbla
bli;"blo";otherbla
```

One solution is to not use echo in the script but use sed directly on the file and storing the resulting csv in a new file:

```
$ sed -e 's/\\\"/""/ig' test.csv > test-tmp.csv
$ cat test-tmp.csv
bla;""bli bli"";otherbla
ble;""bli bli"";otherbla
bli;""blo"";otherbla
```

Then, as pointed into the comments, to avoid clobbering and wrong replacements of quoted fields finishing by `\`, we can use 2 sed expressions, and include the field separator to ensure we replace *only* the `\"` preceding or following the field separator (in my example, the field separator is `;`) but this one doesn't take into account fields single quoted with a `\` as last character in the field such as the `blo` line:

```
$ cat test.csv
bla;\"bli bli\";otherbla
ble;""bli bli"";otherbla
bli;\"blo\";otherbla
blo;"bli bli\";otherbla
blu;""bli bli\"";otherbla

$ sed -e 's/;\\\"/;""/ig' -e 's/\\\";/"";/ig' test.csv
bla;""bli bli"";otherbla
ble;""bli bli"";otherbla
bli;""blo"";otherbla
blo;"bli bli"";otherbla
blu;""bli bli\"";otherbla
```

If you have several sed command, you can put the in a script, it works the same way:

```
$ cat s.sed 
s/\\\"/""/g
```

Using it:

```
$ echo 'bla;\"bli bli\";otherbla' | sed -f s.sed 
bla;""bli bli"";otherbla

sed -f s.sed test.csv > test-tmp.csv
```

Comment: How will you avoid clobbering fields which end in a backslash (and end in backslaah-doublequote when quoted)? This kind of solution can only be applied if you know there is no such data. Otherwise, you make a mistake which you cannot undo (save by having backed up the data first).

Comment: Strange. `echo 'bla;\"bli bli\";otherbla' | sed -e 's/\\"/""/g'` works in a bash script as well.

Comment: @choroba this works because we're able to simple quote `'` escape the line, however, when reading a file, you end up with a variable which, when echo'ed, can be escaped only with double quotes `"`

Comment: Oh, I did not get the line was being echoed from a variable :-o

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the case where one of the fields legitimately ends in a \ character? The quoted representation in the CSV file will end with a backslash followed by a quote; sed solutions such as yours and Thomas's will clobber it.

This is why sed is the wrong tool for working with quoted csv; some problems can only be solved recursively in a proper language (awk, Perl or whatever)